# iOS, running two SDK (plugin) packages in one app

Tags: c#, android, ios

I just need to know, we are building an app and for it to have all the functionality we need it has to run two third party SDK(plugin/kernel) packages. We are getting errors and I just want to know, is this possible to do with iOS, it works perfectly in Android.

Here are some of the errors I am getting
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON in:

```
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-    dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-   iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJSON.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-   iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJSON.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJSON.jsonParser in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJSON.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJSON.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJSON.jsonWriter in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJSON.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJSON.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJSON in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJSON.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJSON.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonBase in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonBase.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonBase.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJsonBase.depth in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonBase.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonBase.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJsonBase.errorTrace in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonBase.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonBase.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJsonBase.maxDepth in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonBase.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonBase.o)
     duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonBase in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonBase.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonBase.o)
     duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonBase.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonBase.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonParser.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonParser.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJsonParser.c in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonParser.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonParser.o)
    [11:13:03 AM] Rakesh Kiron: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonParser in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonParser.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonParser.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonWriter in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonWriter.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonWriter.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJsonWriter.humanReadable in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonWriter.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonWriter.o)
    symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJsonWriter.sortKeys in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonWriter.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonWriter.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonWriter in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AKTest-dyqvtearxdsehagqgoqznsbcegfu/Build/Intermediates/AKTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/AKTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SBJsonWriter.o
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(SBJsonWriter.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_WTARObjectInterface in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(WTARObjectInterface-EAE25FBA022FD861.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WTARObjectInterface in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(WTARObjectInterface-EAE25FBA022FD861.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_WTTrackerInterface in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(WTTrackerInterface-C7F3C07848048053.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WTTrackerInterface in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(WTTrackerInterface-C7F3C07848048053.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_WTTrackable2dObjectInterface in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(WTTrackable2dObjectInterface-E5FBF6EFA7F12643.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WTTrackable2dObjectInterface in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(WTTrackable2dObjectInterface-E5FBF6EFA7F12643.o)
    duplicate symbol __ZN26iOSPlatformServiceProvider11stopServiceESs in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
    duplicate symbol __ZN26iOSPlatformServiceProvider12startServiceESs in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
     duplicate symbol __ZN26iOSPlatformServiceProvider26getPlatformServiceProviderEv in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
    duplicate symbol __ZN26iOSPlatformServiceProviderC1EP6UIViewP7CALayer in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
    duplicate symbol __ZN26iOSPlatformServiceProviderC2EP6UIViewP7CALayer in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
    duplicate symbol __ZTI26iOSPlatformServiceProvider in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
    duplicate symbol __ZTS26iOSPlatformServiceProvider in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
     duplicate symbol __ZTV26iOSPlatformServiceProvider in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(iOSPlatformServiceProvider-576A05213373E338.o)
     duplicate symbol _OPENSSL_showfatal in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(cryptlib.o
    [11:13:20 AM] Rakesh Kiron:     /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(cryptlib.o)
    duplicate symbol _OpenSSLDie in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(cryptlib.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(cryptlib.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_free_locked in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_malloc in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem.o)
    d uplicate symbol _CRYPTO_realloc in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_free in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_push_info_ in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem_dbg.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_pop_info in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem_dbg.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_realloc_clean in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem.o)
    duplicate symbol _OPENSSL_cleanse in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem_clr.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem_clr.o)
    duplicate symbol _cleanse_ctr in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem_clr.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem_clr.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_is_mem_check_on in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem_dbg.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem_dbg.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_mem_ctrl in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(mem_dbg.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(mem_dbg.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_get_ex_data in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(ex_data.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(ex_data.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_set_ex_data in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(ex_data.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(ex_data.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_free_ex_data in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(ex_data.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(ex_data.o)
    duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_new_ex_data in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(ex_data.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(ex_data.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJ_NAME_init in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(o_names.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(o_names.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJ_NAME_get in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(o_names.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(o_names.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJ_obj2nid in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(obj_dat.o)
       /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(obj_dat.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJ_nid2sn in:
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/trunk_1_1_1/iOS/SDK/SDK/lib/Release-iphoneos/libWikitudeSDK.a(obj_dat.o)
    /Users/rakeshkiron/Desktop/apple image recognition/AurasmaKit-1.4.26 (1)/AurasmaKit/libAurasmaKit.a(obj_dat.o)
```

Comment: what are the third party SDKs and what are the errors you get ?

Comment: It is duplicate errors, I am not getting this in Android.

Comment: Here are the errors I am getting

Answer (score 0):

there are two places that u have the same thing. Delete one of them and the error will go off... For example, you have two places where SBJsonWriter is defined... type SBJsonWriter in the search bar to find the two places..

Comment: Ok thanks, but both sdk's use these things, so If I delete one, will both sdk'sstill find it from their libraries?

Comment: put the user header search paths under build settings in search to your folder.. so that it will search for the item in all folders.. remember to put it recursively..